# How to set htpasswd for all except LAN?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, htpasswd

How can I set `htpasswd` prompt for everyone who want to access some server except people from LAN `(192.168.0.*)` ?

Thanks for the answers !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

someting like this :

```
                    Order allow,deny
                    AuthType Basic
                    AuthName "Only for administrator"
                    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords/admin.pwd
                    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
                    Require valid-user
                    Allow from 192.168.10 10.8.0 182.243.107.122 82.122.29.22
                    Satisfy Any
```

:D

Comment: Ok, works fine ! Instead of your `Allow from 192.168.10 10.8.0 ...` it should be `Allow from 192.168.`